# Method to consume letter in a textfield

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a field to register notes regarding an specific transaction in the business, i want the JTextField to only allow to write a maximum of 200 letters and then start to consume() them. I know you can make this with KeyListener but i haven't found anything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Do you want to consume all text as soon as its size reaches 200?

Comment: Yes i want to consume all the text after the 200 letters.

Comment: No, don't use a KeyListener! There are other listeners you should be using. Either a DocumentListener or a DocumentFilter. I suggest the DocumentFilter in my answer below.

Comment: Ok @camickr i'm going to use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a DocumentFilter. The Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) has an example that actually does this.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep a string in a JTextField within a certain length you need to get the text and check if it is greater than your max text length, and just throw away whatever is greater.

```
private void setMaxTextLength(JTextField textField) {
    if(textField.getText().length() > MAXLENGTH) {
        textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0, MAXLENGTH));
    }
}
```